# Why do I have to double click on the pagination nav so that the page number can be selected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pagination, vue-component

I have two component vue

My first component / parent component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <page-listing
          :lastPage="lastPage"
          :perPage="perPage"
          :page="page"
          :changePage="changePage"
        ></page-listing>
    ...
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
import PageListing from "@/views/app/reports/PageListing";

export default {
  components: {
    "page-listing": PageListing
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getReport"]),
    changePage(pageNum) {
      this.loadPage(pageNum);
    },
    loadPage(page){
      this.geReport({page});
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      perPage: "reportPerpage",
      lastPage: "reportLastPage",
    }),
    page: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.reportPage
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setReportPage', newValue); 
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    search() {
      this.page = 1;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadPage();
  }
};
</script>
```

My second component /child component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
      <b-colxx xxs="12">
        <b-pagination-nav
          :number-of-pages="lastPage"
          :link-gen="linkGen"
          :value="page"
          @change="(a)=>changePage(a)"
          :per-page="perPage"
          align="center"
          use-router
        >
        </b-pagination-nav>
      </b-colxx>
    ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: [
    "items",
    "lastPage",
    "perPage",
    "page",
    "changePage",
  ],
  methods: {
    linkGen(pageNum) {
      return pageNum === 1 ? '?' : `?page=${pageNum}`
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

The pagination works. When I load the page, the pagination appears and I click page 2, the list success appears. But page number two is not selected. I have to click 2x so it can be selected

How can I solve this problem?

Please help. Thanks

Note :

I use https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination-nav?page=2

Comment: Check with your devtools what is the state on the first and second click.

Comment: @kissu I created a new question about this case. Maybe you can help me. Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73434454/why-line-number-doesnt-work-when-click-on-another-page

Comment: You can actually edit the current question, no need to create a new one.

Comment: @kissu Yes you are right. Next question I will follow your advice. How do you have any ideas to solve my problem? I'm stuck